# Regex to match ulimit within bracket portion

Tags: regex, linux

Here is the output.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 104448
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 16320
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I want to have a regex that matches all the (blocks, -c), (kbytes, -d), (-e) and so on... from each line.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex like the following:

```
\([a-z\s\d,-]+\)
```

Comment: You missed a `\d` here is it. It works. `\([a-z\s\d,-]+\)` Thanks

Comment: Yes! Corrected. You can of course have a more wider pattern to match.